# Draw axis lines or the origin for Matplotlib contour plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I want to draw `x=0` and `y=0` axis in my contour plot, using a white color.  If that is too cumbersome, I would like to have a white dot denoting where the origin is.

My contour plot looks as follows and the code to create it is given below.

```
xvec = linspace(-5.,5.,100)                               
X,Y = meshgrid(xvec, xvec)                                
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))                      
contourf(X, Y, W,100)                             
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]

Answer (score 90, accepted):

There are a number of options (E.g. [centered spines](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/spine_placement_demo.html)), but in your case, it's probably simplest to just use [`axhline`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=axvline#matplotlib.pyplot.axvline) and [`axvline`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=axvline#matplotlib.pyplot.axhline).

E.g.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xvec = np.linspace(-5.,5.,100)                               
x,y = np.meshgrid(xvec, xvec)
z = -np.hypot(x, y)                                

plt.contourf(x, y, z, 100)                             
plt.colorbar() 

plt.axhline(0, color='white')
plt.axvline(0, color='white')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: `spine.set_position('zero')` is the way to go, why do you recommend drawing lines manually instead?

Comment: Is it possible to use what the above comment suggests without having the axis object?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just overlay a straight line?

```
plt.plot([0,0],[-4,4],lw=3,'w')
```

Comment: This line generates and error. Please explain it further